# Checkbox is still showing true when unchecked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Ok, so I'm currently having an issue with the $.prop('checked') functionality. When unchecking some of my boxes, and using this function to read the checkboxes, all of them are still showing up as true when some of them should be showing up as unchecked. The part of the function that checks this is below, but some background: I'm using a table with input values in each td element and due to the way it's written, I'm having to gather all the info / validate / and check by using a td.each() function.

```
    $("td", ele).each(function(idx){
            var before  = $('.e_content', this),
                b_name  = $('input:last[type!="hidden"], textarea:last, checkbox:last, select:last', this).attr('name'),
                b_val   = $('input[name="'+b_name+'"], select:last, textarea[name="'+b_name+'"]', this).val(),
                b_chx   = $('input:checkbox[name="'+b_name+'"]', this).prop('checked'),
                after   = function(){
                    before.hide();
                    $(ele).css("background", color);
                    $('td.edit', ele).show();
                    $('td.save', ele).hide();
                    $('span', this)
                        // WORKING ON TAKING THE VALUE OF THE .e_content FORM AND REPLACING THE SPAN WITH IT
                        .html(function(){
                            console.log(b_name+' : '+b_chx);
                            if(b_val != undefined && b_val != ''){
                                if(b_name == 'StageType'){
                                    if(b_val == 1){ return 'Voice'; }
                                    if(b_val == 2){ return 'Text'; }
                                    if(b_val == 3){ return 'Email'; }
                                }
                                else if(b_name == 'qtrhour') {
                                    return $('select', before).find(':selected').text();
                                }
                                else if(b_chx == true) { return '&check;'; }
                                else if(b_chx == false) { return '&cross;'; }
                                else {
                                    if(before.find('input:last').prop('type') != 'checkbox')
                                        return b_val.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
                                }
                            }




                        })
                        .show();
                };
            $(this).html(after);
        });
```

The problem is with this line:

```
b_chx   = $('input:checkbox[name="'+b_name+'"]', this).prop('checked'),
```

It's coming up always as true even when the checkbox has been unchecked before the save button is hit. This function fires on the .save click event. Hopefully this is enough to determine what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
 $('input:checkbox[name="'+b_name+'"]', this).is(':checked');
```

Comment: Unfortunally it's getting the same value as the .prop('checked'). There all pulling true, which is where I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues regarding to checking or unchecking checkboxes, I normally use jQuery.attr()

```
$(...).attr('checked')
$(...).attr('checked','checked')
$(...).removeAttr('checked')
```

Also sometimes I check or uncheck them binding or triggering a .click() function.